# How to select rows between x and y in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I can select the `TOP` rows from a `Redshift` table by using the `TOP` clause. But I would like to select the rows between, say, 10 and 20. I am using the `ORDER BY` clause, so the resultset is consistent.

How do I do that?

I would ideally like something like:

```
SELECT * BETWEEN 10 AND 20
FROM <tablename>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more traditional method in Redshift would be `LIMIT`/`OFFSET`.  For the second set of 10 rows:

```
select t.*
from t
order by XXX
limit 10 offset 9;
```

Note that the offset is one less than the row where you want to start (i.e. offset `0` = "first row").

This is also the syntax used in Postgres.